# Is there a way to open a commit in Bitbucket cloud from VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Something like Vim's [vim-fubitive](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-fubitive) plugin.

Tried google but I can't find anything on this. Just started with VS code so maybe I'm missing some plugins.